# Search records in a table with the same date or entering into this date range. Sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Learn sql and came the next question. How to implement a query to be showing a record that would have been identical in the two fields, or included in these ranges: data-time and data-time-end.

There is a table:

```
broadcasting
rows: id, data-time, data-time-end, nameprogramm, namechannel
```

some data are:

```
'1 ', '2012-01-09 13:00:00', '2012-01-09 13:30:00 ','News', 'Channel1'
'2 ', '2012-01-09 13:00:00', '2012-01-09 13:30:00 ','News', 'Channel2'
'3 ', '2012-01-09 13:05:00', '2012-01-09 13:35:00 ','News', 'Channel3'
'4 ', '2012-01-09 13:10:00', '2012-01-09 13:15:00 ','News', 'Channel4'
'5 ', '2012-01-09 11:00:00', '2012-01-09 12:00:00 ','News', 'Channel5'
'6 ', '2012-01-09 16:00:00', '2012-01-09 18:00:00 ','News', 'Channel6'
```

need to query brought:

```
date-time date-time-end channel
```

for those records that are in the range of date-time and date-time-end.

I think you need to select the maximum and minimum time. Then see if other records are in this range. But something is when it turns out, I will implement it. Thank you!

---------------------Add

Let me explain by the example of television programs.
We have the channels and transmission.
At what time news from the different channels are transmitted at one time? How many news channels broadcast at the same time? (The start time news is not necessarily the same).

results:
I want the result was as follows:

```
data-time             data-time-end         namechannel
2012-01-09 13:00:00 | 2012-01-09 13:30:00 | Channel1
2012-01-09 13:05:00 | 2012-01-09 13:35:00 | Channel3
2012-01-09 13:10:00 | 2012-01-09 13:15:00 | Channel4
```

Comment: This sounds like a very basic question. You would be better off with a tutorial or a book on SQL.

Comment: You should try to edit your post. Your english makes it very hard to understand what you need help for.

Comment: Excuse for my English. I need to deduce all records which get to ranges data-time, data-time-end. An announcement in one site of time at what records?

Comment: @Feor: Shouldn't Channel2's record also be included in the expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select records where the **whole** of the date range is between the specified start and end date, try:

```
select * from broadcasting 
where `date-time` >= ? /* start of date range */
  and `date-time-end` <= ? /* end of date range */
```

To select records where **any part** of the date range is between the specified start and end date, try:

```
select * from broadcasting 
where `date-time` <= ? /* end of date range */
  and `date-time-end` >= ? /* start of date range */
```

EDIT: To select records where any part of their date range overlaps any part of any other record's date range for the same program, try:

```
select * from broadcasting b1
where exists (select null
              from broadcasting b2
              where b1.nameprogramm = b2.nameprogramm and
                    b1.`date-time` <= b2.`date-time-end` and 
                    b2.`date-time` <= b1.`date-time-end` and
                    b1.id <> b2.id)
```

Comment: It almost that that is necessary! Whether But how to check up records enter into the given range? Records with time 
' 2012-01-09 11:00:00 AM ', ' 2012-01-09 0:00:00 PM'
' 2012-01-09 11:10:00 AM ', ' 2012-01-09 0:00:00 PM'
' 2012-01-09 11:20:00 AM ', ' 2012-01-09 0:00:00 PM'
All should be deduced. Thanks!

Comment: @Feor: I'm afraid I can't understand what you are asking. Perhaps you could edit your post, and give some examples of what you would like to see (both input data and expected results)?

Comment: @Feor: That's not actually an example of **expected results**.

Comment: Posted by. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Thank you for your decision! Can do to it will write out the data only for name = "news"?

Comment: @Feor: Sure - add the condition `and b1.nameprogramm = 'News'` to the end of the query.